# Python Class construction: why is my class constructed with __init__ different than the class constructed from dict using setattr?

Tags: python

A simplified version of my class:

```
class A:
    classVar = 'Foo'
    def __init__(self, instanceVar):
        self.instanceVar = instanceVar
    @classmethod
    def fromDict(cls, indict):
        for key, item in indict.items():
            setattr(cls, key, item)
        if 'instanceVar' not in indict:
            setattr(cls, 'instanceVar', None)
        return cls
    def aFunction(self):
        print(self.classVar, self.instanceVar)
a = A('Bar')
_a = A.fromDict({'instanceVar' : 'Bar'})
__a = A.fromDict({})
```

Why does `a.aFunction()` give me: `Foo Bar`
But `_a.aFunction()` and `__a.aFunction()` give me the error: `TypeError: aFunction() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'`?
What am I doing wrong when dynamically constructing my class from a dictionary here?

I basically need to be able to give a class function both a class constructed from `__init__` and be able to feed it classes constructed from dictionaries. Right now the `TypeError: aFunction() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'` is throwing me for a loop.

Comment: Your `fromDict` method is modifying, and returning, *the class itself* - it's not creating an instance of the class, if that's what you were expecting it to do.

Comment: What is the required output when you call `aFunction()` on each of your instances?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The point of `fromDict` is to create an *instance* of `cls`, rather than trying to add additional class attributes to the class. You still need to explicitly create the instance; you just have the opportunity to initialize that object in ways not handled by `__init__` itself.

```
class A:
    classVar = 'Foo'
    def __init__(self, instanceVar):
        self.instanceVar = instanceVar

    @classmethod
    def fromDict(cls, indict):
        obj = cls(indict.get('instanceVar'))

        for key, item in indict.items():
            setattr(obj, key, item)
        
        return obj

    def aFunction(self):
        print(self.classVar, self.instanceVar)
```

However, `fromDict` should restrict itself to *finding* values to add to the object; `__init__` should still be responsible for *using* them to initialize the object. Something like

```
class A:
    classVar = 'Foo'

    def __init__(self, instanceVar, **kwargs):
        self.instanceVar = instanceVar
        for k, v in kwargs.items():
            setattr(self, k, v)

    @classmethod
    class fromDict(cls, indict):
        d = dict(indict)
        if 'instanceVar' not in d:
            d['instanceVar'] = None
        return cls(**d)

    ...
```